# How to initialize component's root dom element in Vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

In React use of arrow function does the trick

```
class AppComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createAppComponent()
  }

  createAppComponent() {
    const node = this.node

  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={node => this.node = node}></div>
  }
}
```

How can I initialize same `node` property in Vue component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Vue*, you use the `$el` of a `ref` to get the underlying DOM element.

```
<my-widget ref='theWidget' />
```

```
mounted() {
   const theElement = this.$refs.theWidget.$el
}
```

## Other Comments

If you define the `ref` in a loop, 'theWidget' will be an array.

If the 'component' is just an HTML element (e.g. `div` or `input`) `$el` will be undefined because 'theWidget' will be the component reference.

Comment: Hi Steven. I've got `this.$refs.theWidget.$el = undefined`. From other hand if I insert 2 instances of same component `this.$refs.theWidget` will return latest reference. That is the problem with Vue's `ref`.  it works like a hashmap. You can't store two instances under one key.

Comment: Keep in mind:  If you define the ref in a loop, theWidget will be an array.  Also, if the 'component' is just an HTML element (e.g. div or input) $el will be undefined because 'theWidget' will be the component reference.  Set a breakpoint and have a look at 'this.$refs', or console.log it.  That is the best way to see what's going on 'under-the-hood'.  I will add these thoughts to the solution, too.